# Python one line if-else with different operators

Tags: python, conditional-expressions, augmented-assignment

I was fiddling with one line if and for statements in python and ran across the following problem:

I can make something like the following work:

```
state = 1 if state == 4 else 2
```

But I want to use = and += in the same context, something like this:

```
state = 1 if state == 4 else state+=1
```

How can I implement this in one line?

Comment: `state = 1 if state == 4 else state + 1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`+=` is not an operator, it is a *statement*. You cannot use statements in an expression.

Since `state` is an integer, just use `+`, which *is* an operator:

```
state = 1 if state == 4 else state + 1
```

The end result is exactly the same as having used an `+=` in-place addition.

Better still, use the `%` modulus operator:

```
state = (state % 4) + 1
```

which achieves what you wanted to achieve in the first place; limit `state` to a value between `1` and `4`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because [assignment](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) is not an [expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#expressions) in Python.

Only expressions have a value in Python, which is different from JavaScript for example - where almost anything, including assignments, have a value.

You can write your program like this, however:

```
state = 1 if state == 4 else state + 1
```

This makes the value conditional on the state, not the assignment. It works in your case since the state variable is always assigned a new value.

In the general case, let's say you want to update different variables depending on the current state, you should stick to a regular `if` statement. Don't overuse the ternary operator (`x if C else y`) - only use it if it makes your code more readable.

Comment: I just saw that @vaultah wrote this same answer in the comments. I didn't see you there, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You are already assigning the result to `state` so you could just:

```
state = 1 if state == 4 else state + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative way to do this is:
var = test and "when true" or "when false"

```
state = state == 4 and 1 or state + 1
```

The modulus answer is better for this but the above is useful shortcut

Answer (score 0):

using lambda:

```
state = (lambda n:[n+1,0][n==4] )(state)
```

so, in essence:

`[n+1,0][1]`  # True(1): means get index#1, which is 0
`[n+1,0][0]`  # False(0):means get index#0, which is n+1

To make it more readable, I will break it down to a function:

```
def myfunc(n):
    ans = [ n+1, 0 ]
    if n==4:
        return ans[1] # which is the value 0
    else:
        return ans[0] # which is n+1

state=6
state=myfunc(state) # returns 7
state=4
state=myfunc(state) # returns 0
```

Comment: Can you improve your answer by explaining why this works?